# Order form in joomla does not submit data

Tags: javascript, joomla1.7

I have Joomla 1.7 working.I want to include order form in one of the pages.I have this part of the code but the problem is that it is not submitting the data to the email.How can I change the data for it to be submitted?This is part of the code.

```
<div class="orderform"><form id="order_form" method="post" name="order_form">&gt;
<table>
<tbody id="personal_info">
<tr class="label"><th colspan="2">Personal Information</th></tr>
<tr id="row_firstname">
<td class="label">
 <div><label for="firstname">First name:<span class="required_star">*</span></label>

</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
    <div id="error_firstname" class="validation_error">Enter your first name</div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_lastname">
    <td class="label">
    <div><label for="lastname">Last name:<span class="required_star">*</span></label></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
    <div id="error_lastname" class="validation_error">Enter your last name</div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_email">
    <td class="label">
     <div><label for="email">Email:<span class="required_star">*</span></label></div>
      </td>
     <td>
     <div><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" />
     <div id="error_email" class="validation_error">Enter valid email address</div>
     </div>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="row_retype_email">
     <td class="label">
     <div><label for="retype_email">Re-type email:<span class="required_star">*</span></ label></div>
     </td>
     <td>
     <div><input id="retype_email" type="text" name="retype_email" value="" />
     <div id="error_retype_email" class="validation_error">Emails do not coincide</div>
     </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need php for that something like:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
        $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['homepage'] != "") {
        $homepage = filter_var($_POST['homepage'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        if (!filter_var($homepage, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $errors .= "$homepage is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid URL.<br/><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your home page.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['message'] != "") {
        $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['message'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $mail_to = 'me@somewhere.com';
        $subject = 'New Mail from Form Submission';
        $message  = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
        $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
        $message .= 'Homepage: ' . $_POST['homepage'] . "\n";
            $message .= "Message:\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n";
        //mail($to, $subject, $message);

        echo "Thank you for your email!<br/><br/>";
    } else {
        echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';
    }
}
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="form-email.php">
Name: <br/>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" size="50" /><br/><br/>
Email Address: <br/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" size="50"/> <br/><br/>
Home Page: <br/>
<input type="text" name="homepage" value="<?php echo $_POST['homepage']; ?>" size="50" /> <br/><br/>
Message: <br/>
<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Just make sure that name of your FORM page is : form-email.php (look for action inside FORM HTML and change it if you want). This script is tested and it is working you just need to insert it correctly into your Joomla page.